# async ajax within background.js of chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

this is my background.js

```
   chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
      chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
          conditions: [
            // When a page contains a <video> tag...
            new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
              pageUrl: { hostEquals: 'www.youtube.com'}
            })
          ],
          // ... show the page action.
          actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
        }]);
      });
    });
```

where should I insert my ajax? and how to use jquery? like $.post in my background.js?

Comment: It's impossible to guess what you're trying to achieve from your question.

Comment: @Xan edited my question, sorry.